# In ASP.net core, How to Reload the _layout page when retun view()

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to refresh the _layout page for updating data in the layout section, when a action method returns a view().
Currently when I am returning the View(), layout page data are not updating.

Comment: "updating data in the layout section" How you load your data? Could you share your code ?

Comment: Loading the data from session. In the action method we updating the session values and returning the view(), But not affecting on the _layout page.

Comment: Are you sure about what _layout_ page are you trying to update? Do you have another _layout_ page in the discovery path used by the engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a demo to use session to pass the string to appear in _layout page in every page , you can refer to it.

1.Register IHttpContextAccessor and session in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
...
app.UseSession();
```

2.In the controller, set a session variable:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Photo", "p1");
```

3.In _layout.cshtml, inject IHttpContextAccessor implementation and use it to get the HttpContext and Session object from that.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
...
@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Photo")
```

result:

[image]